# Make a PHP exception trigger a Symfony form validation error

Tags: php, forms, symfony, braintree

I'm adding billing pages to a web app I've built using Symfony. These are a standard credit card payment and billing history type pages.

I'm collecting user order data, billing address etc, using Symfony forms and sending that data to the Braintree API using their [PHP SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php).

If the Braintree server rejects some data because the format is invalid the Braintree SDK throws a PHP Exception.

How can I catch these exceptions and trigger form errors on my Symfony forms?

FYI a long list of the Braintree error codes can be viewed [here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/lib/Braintree/Error/Codes.php). There are a lot so I really don't want to replicate each of these manually with `@Assert/Length(max = 9)` or `@Assert\Regex("/^\w+/")` etc, etc... on my form entities. I'd rather map the exceptions directly to the form fields and use the error strings returned by the Braintree API as the form validation messages.

Does anyone know a simple way to achieve this or a better solution?

Many thanks :)

**UPDATE**
I was wrong about the Braintree SDK throwing exceptions. I had some legacy code that was throwing the exceptions. Braintree actually returns the errors in the result object. Here's the [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/validation-errors/overview/php). I can loop through these and add errors to the form using [this](https://deanclatworthy.com/2013/05/silex-tip-1-how-to-quickly-invalidate-a-form-field-in-your-controller/) and either display these at the top of the form, as suggested by Pipe in the comments, or map them to the correct fields.

Comment: If you are sending the form data to braintree, then you are sending the `valid data` no? Why you need to throw it as a validation error on the form? and not simply display an error in your view?

Comment: Yes I follow you and that's what I'm currently doing. However if an API exception is thrown because, for example, the billing address postal code is invalid, then for good UX the error message should be displayed next to the postal code input not at the top of the page, right?

Comment: What if you do `$form->get('yourFieldHere')->addError(new FormError('YourInvalidMessageHere'));`